# Loop with Solver

Tags: vba, loops, excel, solver

I am attempting to program a loop with solver.

```
Sub SharpeRatio()
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:="$Q$18", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$L$18,$M$18", Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$L$18", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$L$18", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$18", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$M$18", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$R$18", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True    
End Sub
```

The solver code works. I need to optimize all cells in column Q while using the constraints of the values in each respective row. I need to do this for rows 14 thru 2843.

I cannot seem to enter in the correct loop. How should I rewrite this?

Answer (score 0):

I would change `"$Letter$18"` to something along the lines of `"$Letter" + i` and then encasing the code in a for loop.

`for i = 14 to 2843
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$Q"+i, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$L"+i,"$M"+i, Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$L"+i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$L"+i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$M"+i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$M"+i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$R"+i, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True

Next`

Something along those lines should work